# To create roles and permission dynamically in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a Ruby on rails project.

There are 5 Tables such as 
**user table; role table; permission table; user_permission table; and role_user table.**

Using a Current User ID,

Here Super Admin should able to create roles and permissions dynamically, I tried using **cancan gem** but getting an error and not working properly, Is there any other solution for this, or can we create it without using any gems?

Kindly tell me any suggestion as i am a beginner

These are the model

```
User  model

 has_many :role_users
 has_many :roles, through: :role_users   
 validates :email,:presence => true
```

---

```
RoleUser  model

 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :role
```

---

```
 Role  model  

 has_many :role_permissions
 has_many :role_users
 has_many :users, through: :role_users
 has_many :permissions, through: :role_permissions
 validates :name, presence: true
```

---

```
RolePermission model

 belongs_to :permission
 belongs_to :role
```

---

```
Permission Model 

 has_many :permission_actions
 has_many :role_permissions
 has_many :roles, through: :role_permissions
 validates :subject_class, presence: true
 validates :action, presence: true
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you mean by a _Super Admin should able to create roles and permissions dynamically_? Can you give an example of the workflow you have in mind? Permissions on specific instances or all objects of one type? Btw what version of Ruby on Rails are you using (you mentioned several different, very old and outdated versions)?

Comment: here everything is dynamic User, roles as well as permission,  A Super Admin create any number of users , Roles(Another super Admin, Admin etc) and Permission(create user, edit user, create roles, edit roles etc) and they can assign user to roles and permissions  and using  Rails 5.1.6

Comment: Rails version 5.1.6

Comment: Do you mean, you have like a `dashboard`, where `Admin` can list all the `users` and `create` them and `assign` a `role` to that `user` ?

Comment: Yes, and the Super admin can also create roles and permissions dynamically

Comment: You can look into **Rolify** gem. You can create roles and assign permissions dynamically. Please go through their documentation:

https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

Hope this helps you finding a solution.

Comment: Ok. You can do this is 2 ways, either use the `rolify` gem or build your own `associations` like you already which might need tweaking. Also, what are the errors you're facing ? Can you paste the logs ?

Comment: Building this feature using you're association structure is not a problem, but why do you want to `reinvent the wheel`, you could use the gem like others have suggested.

Comment: You can replace `RoleUser` and `RolePermission` with HABTM relation.

Comment: I am working on same roles as yours, Can you elaborate what you did?